# I cant center my header

Tags: html, css

Here is the link: http://jessiskiptoncampbell.com/jessi-wp/
At the moment its aligned right, but i want it to be aligned in the center.

```
#header {
    padding: 15px 0 45px 0;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
#logobar1, #logobar2 {
    display:block;
    width:100%;
    position:absolute;
    center:0px;
    z-index:1;
}
#logobar1 {
    border-top:2px solid #231f20;
    border-bottom:2px solid #231f20;
    background-color:#f49cb1;
    height:102px;
    margin-top:197px;
}
#logobar2 {
    background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    height:80px;
    margin-top:208px;
}
#logodiv, #logodiv a, #logo {
    display:block;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:2;
}
.nav {
    text-align: center;
    width: auto;
    margin: -45px auto 15px auto;
    z-index:3;
    position:relative;
    font-family:'Montserrat Alternates', sans-serif;
}
.nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style:none;
}
.nav ul li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 8px;
    font-size: 14px;
    position: relative;
}
.nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding: 2px 20px;
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.nav ul li a:hover, .nav li.current_page_item a, .nav ul li.current-menu-item a {
    color: #931b20;
}
```

Comment: After `#header { ... }` you have to brackets, but no element/ class/ id in front of it...

Comment: @user3338493 if any answers satisfied your needs, then mark that with check.

Answer (score 2):

[image]just Give `width:100%;` for the `.jr_logo` class

Comment: Width: 100%; will not fix the issue for smaller devices - try checking by resizing browser window

Answer (score 1):

Set up your header image width to this `width: 1240px;` and it should be centered

Answer (score 0):

your maincontainer has a margin and its is setting everything off...
take your header out of your maincontainer...

Answer (score 0):

its simple.just give your image an id or class..likeke

```
 #myimg


     {
        float:left; 
        margin-left:-116px;
        }
now it will perfectly become in center.
```